# How to redirect a domain to IP+port?

Tags: apache, apache2, subdomain

I have a website on localhost. On the other hand, I have a program running on localhost:8067.

I would like to manage the next:

- Type `localhost` on the URL and go to the website.
- Type `my.domain.com` on the URL and go to the program.

I am using Apache2 to achieve this, but I cannot.

I created a site in /etc/apache2/sites-available and enabled it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName my.domain.com
  # ServerAlias my.domain.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8067/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8067/

</VirtualHost>
```

This is not working properly. Because with this site enabled, if I type `localhost`, I am redirected to `http://localhost:8067/`, which I do not want, because if I type `localhost`, I have to see the website.

Anyone can help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this will be of any help to you. Please ignore if it was not.

You will have to create two hosts files to achieve this:

Host File 01:
asking the server to listen at 80, for requests for localhost, and feed the root directory through port 80 to those requests.

Host File 02:
asking the server to listen at 80, for requests for my.domain.com and feed the root directory through port 8062 to those requests.

I cannot give you the exact apache configuration for this, because I am more familiar with nginx configuration. However, since you created the above configuration yourself, you won't be having difficulty creating what I said.